# How to automatically infer the return type from a function type?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, boost-python

I'm using `boost::python` to create a Python wrapper of a C++ library. At some point, `boost::python` needs a pointer to a member function (or something compatible), like:

```
template <class MyClass, typename ValueType>
void (*setter_function)(MyClass&, ValueType)

// This doesn't compile, but you got the idea.
my_boost_python_call(setter_function f);
```

Since the class I'm wrapping has its setter in the following form:

```
template <class MyClass, typename ValueType>
MyClass& (MyClass::*setter_method)(ValueType)
```

I wrote a single "conversion" function:

```
template <typename MyClass, typename ValueType, setter_method<MyClass, ValueType> fluent_setter>
void nonfluent_setter(MyClass& instance, ValueType value)
{
  (instance.*fluent_setter)(value);
}
```

Which I can use like that:

```
class Foo
{
  public:

    Foo& bar(int value);
};

my_boost_python_call(nonfluent_setter<Foo, int, &Foo::bar>);
```

So far this works well, but I wonder if there is a way to make this even more "easy" (to use).

Do you think it is somehow possible to get something like:

```
// return type is somehow inferred from the member function pointer
my_boost_python_call(nonfluent_setter<Foo, &Foo::bar>);

// or even a syntax similar to boost::python::make_function
my_boost_python_call(make_nonfluent_setter<Foo>(&Foo::bar));
```

All solutions (even ones that explain how to specialize `boost::python` to handle my specific case) are welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type cannot be automatically deduced in C++ and you cannot overload functions based on return type.

In C++0x there is a new feature called [decltype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype) that might be of interest.

Answer (score 5):

It is actually possible to infer the return type of a function using casting operators -- I describe this [here](http://programmaticallyspeaking.blogspot.se/2012/09/infer-return-type-for-templated.html).

Here's the short version:

```
struct ReturnType {
  template<typename T>
  operator T() {
    // your code for return a T goes here.
  }
};
ReturnType func() { return ReturnType(); }
```

Here, the compiler will infer the value of `T`, thus the return type of `func` is also inferred.

Comment: Since C++11, it is possible to infer function return types [using `auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).