# How to infer correctly a return type for a template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype

**Disclaimer:** I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439769/how-to-automatically-infer-the-return-type-from-a-function-type) and I'm precisely asking how `decltype`, suggested in the accepted answer, can be used for that.

Basically I try (a bit for fun, a bit for convenience, and a bit for learning purpose) to implement small wrappers for the standard algorithms that simplifies their use when applied to a whole container. The main idea is to get rid of `.begin()` and `.end()` and just specify the container on which the algorithm must be applied.

Then, I'd like to know if it's possible (and not stupid by the way) to infer the return type of my wrappers from the standard algorithm return type itself.

For the moment, I tried the following (for std::count):

```
template<class Cnt,
         class T>
inline 
auto count(Cnt _cnt, const T& _val) -> decltype(std::count){}
```

but it gave me an error at compile time:

> Failed to specialize function template ''unknown-type' ragut::count(Cnt,const T &)'

I figured it might not be enough to just say `decltype(std::count)`, and supposed it asked for a more specified argument like that:

```
decltype(std::count<std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag,Cnt::value_type> >)
```

but this gave the same error.

I'd like to know then if it's actually not stupid and possible to do that.

Comment: You probably want to pass the container by const reference.

Comment: @MSalters Right, good point, thanks !

Comment: The good thing is that in C++14 we'll probably be able to leave off the trailing return type. The compiler will figure it out from `return std::count(std::begin(_cnt), std::end(_cnt), _val);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`decltype(x)` denotes the type of the expression `x`. In other words, you're trying to create a function returning a function template (in the first case) or a function (in the second case). That won't work. You want the type of a *call* to `std::count`, like this:

```
template<class Cnt,
         class T>
inline 
auto count(Cnt _cnt, const T& _val) 
  -> decltype(std::count(std::begin(_cnt), std::end(_cnt), _val)))
{ }
```

Comment: Using `std::begin(_cnt)` would also allow it to be called with an array. (Assuming you don't copy `_cnt`)

Comment: Ok nailed it. Difference between the type of the function actually specified, and its return type. Thus, IIUC, `decltype(std::count)` actually gives me the type of the function (i.e. "function that take these arguments and return that") instead of its return type, right ?

Comment: @JBL Pretty much. Except that `std::count` is a function tempate, so `decltype(std::count)` doesn't even give a valid type. But if you have e.g. a function `int foo();`, then `decltype(foo)` will indeed be "function taking no arguments and returning `int`."

Answer (score 1):

It would work, if you specify the correct template arguments. In this case, those would be `<typename Cnt::const_iterator, typename Cnt::value_type>`

Comment: No, it wouldn't. That would make the OP's `count` return a function type.

Comment: Fair point, you'd actually need a [`function_traits`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7943765/15416) class for that too.